# CSS background image disappears after hover

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, background

I'm having a problem in Google Chrome. I'm using a simple hover state on a `display:block;` link to change only the `background:url();` property on the hover.

Google Chrome shows the actual hover change ok, but when I mouse out of the area, the background goes transparent/disappears.

Here's my CSS:

```
#branding #logo a {
width: 259px;
height: 201px;
border:none;
display: block;
background:url(images/logo.png) top left;
}
#branding #logo a:hover {
background:url(images/logo_hover.png) top left;
}
```

The actual site is here: http://beerblestudy.org. Again this is only happening for me in Chrome. Any thoughts?

Comment: On a slow connection the first hover takes a second or two to load. You should preload the hover image to avoid this: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/28/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: Or, even better, a sprite image.

Comment: Yes, please use sprites for rollovers - it's *2012*.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me an all browsers. Try deleting your cache because it's working normally. I recomment you to delete the lines `top left` since they aren't necessary

Comment: Hm, I've cleared my cache several times, and still it disappears. I also just tried adding `top left` as a possible solution. Thought specifying might help Chrome out. I guess if it's showing up for you, then I'm ok with it, haha. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So then reset your chrome navigatio ndata, delete ALL because its working fine for me

Comment: I'm seeing it disappear in Chrome as well.

Comment: I'm also seeing it disappear in chrome

Comment: That's strange, http://i40.tinypic.com/1zciemb.png (Screenshot working on chrome) ???

Comment: After some time not working on the site, the rollover is working fine in Chrome now. Maybe a cache issue then. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your background is disappearing in chrome here too.

I know I shouldn't "me too" on here, but this is odd and what brought me here was the same problem I'm having on a site I built recently: http://macvillain.com - the right hand column image blocks.

I tested thoroughly on most browsers (not ie6 or 7 - I've banished them) and has been fine in chrome for the past two weeks until today. Sometimes clearing cache etc works for a little while then it comes back. I don't get it...

UPDATE:

Hi I got an answer on the Google Chrome forum which said:
"Chrome uses strictly HTML5.  Validate HTML code http://validator.w3.org/"

I had forgotten to do this and there were a couple of invalid things which I fixed and now all is fine and dandy.

I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique:  I saw a JQuery plugin that automatically download images specified in CSS style sheets.

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/